# Shared service variable is undefined?

Tags: angular

I have a service that has the following method:

```
public GetCaseData(){

const url =  environment.api_url;

const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return this._http.get(url, { headers: headers })
    .map(response => {
        return response.json();
    });
}
```

In my app.component.ts, I am calling it like this:

```
  constructor(private _caseService : CaseService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this._caseService.GetCaseData().subscribe(data => {
      this._caseService.caseData = data;

    });

  }
```

I want to share `this._caseService.caseData` to my other components `Home` and `Contact`, but in OnInit of those components, this._caseService.caseData is undefined.
Here is home for example,

```
 constructor(private _caseService: CaseService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this._caseService.caseData); //is undefined here because it
                                            // is called before the data comes back
}
```

I know why (because the components are initialized before the data comes back), but I am not sure how to fix it?

I put a getter in my home and I see the data rendered.  Does the getter get called later in the lifecycle after data has been returned:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this._caseService.caseData;
    console.log('this.data ', this.data) //undefined
  }

  get caseData()
  {
    return this._caseService.caseData; //data rendered on html page
  }
```

When I do the following, it says it expects a `:` instead of `data.`  It also complains that there should be a `,` by the `ngOnInit` closing `}`

ngOnInit() {
    this.concatCaseData$ = this._caseService.caseData$.map(data => { 
     return { data.OfficialCaseName}
   }

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add on to Elseo answer, Getter would fix your issue as it is constantly being called.

The other alternative, which I think is a better solution, is to use BehaviorSubject. As you can give it a initial state and you subscribe to it.

For example, your `CaseService`:

```
private caseDataStore = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
public caseData$ = this.caseDataStore.asObservable();

public GetCaseData(){

const url =  environment.api_url;

const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return this._http.get(url, { headers: headers })
    .map(response => {
        return response.json();
    }).toPromise().then(res => {
    caseDataStore.next(res);
});
}
```

On your app component, you will call `GetCaseData` to trigger the rest call and subscribe to the subject.

```
public caseData; 
ngOninit() {
    this._caseService.GetCaseData()
  // you can either subscribe and put it into local state, or you can pipe 
  // async into the template directly. 
    this._caseService.caseData$.subscribe( res => {
    this.caseData = res;
}) 
}
```

and lastly on your other components, you can just subscribe.

```
this._caseService.caseData$.subscribe( res => {
        this.caseData = res;
    })
```

---

UPDADE: To elaborate on async pipe.

Async pipe is awesome! It is a handy helper that allow us to subscribe to observable without worrying about unsubscribe. Reduces A LOT of boiler plate in my code. To use `async` pipe in your example:

instead of doing this on the component

```
 this._caseService.caseData$.subscribe( res => {
        this.caseData = res;
 })
```

you can have this in your html

```
 <div> {{ _caseService.caseData$ | async }} </div>
```

A word of caution though, each time you use `async`, it creates a new subscription. so the following will create duplicate subscription.

```
 <div> {{ (_caseService.caseData$ | async)?.prop1 }} </div>
 <div> {{ (_caseService.caseData$ | async)?.prop2 }} </div>
 <div> {{ (_caseService.caseData$ | async)?.prop3 }} </div>
```

To get away from this, you can use

```
  <div *ngIf="_caseService.caseData$  | async as caseData">
      <div> {{caseData.prop1}} <div>
      <div> {{caseData.prop2}} <div>
      <div> {{caseData.prop3}} <div>
  </div>
```

---

UDPATE 2: If you are already using angular 5, use httpclient! it automatically format your REST resposne as JSON. Don't need to map it anymore.

```
this._http.get(url, { headers: headers }).toPromise().then(res => {
   caseDataStore.next(res);
});
```

I used `toPromise`in the service because this is a one off call, and don't want to unsubscribe afterward. Alternatively, I have seen others use `.first()`.

---

UPDATE 3: If you only want to be selective on the property you are getting from your component, you can `map` or `pluck` it from your observable.

Assuming you are using async pipe already, in your contact component.

```
public contactCaseData$ = this._caseService.caseData$.map( data => { 
    return {data.prop1, data.prop2}
}
```

now just subscribe as usual. If you want to take this 1 step further! You can write your map pipe in your app.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";

@Pipe({
  name: 'map'
})
export class MapPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(o$, propsNames): any {
    return o$.map(res => {
      return propsNames.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        acc[cur] = res[cur];
        return acc;
      }, {})
    })
  }

}
```

Demo of how that works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ftxyns?file=app%2Fmap.pipe.ts

Comment: Thanks, I have a few questions:  1) What is this.sidebarStatusStore.AsObservable()?  2) What does toPromise do in this example?  3) Can you elaborate a bit more on local state vs async pipe?

Comment: Ah I copy and paste a project I'm working on. Updated

Comment: Updated! async pipe is only a helper that allows you write less code. I prefer it over local state as I don't have to write unsubscribe logic. RxJs is quite powerful, if utilize properly by chaining your operators, it often reduces the view layer to just a subscription.

Comment: Wow, thanks I got it working with local state...I am going to try the async now.  What is the difference between BehaviorSubject and Subject?

Comment: Behavior subject takes in an initial state, and each subscription will automatically gets the last value. As oppose to subject, which will get only value when the subscription is already established.

Comment: Awesome, I got the async pipe working.  One last question,  let's say I want to share only a single property from my object to my navbar component.  Right now, the whole object is being shared.  Is there a simple way to only share the relevant parts to different components?  For example, the contact component does not need as many of the properties as the home component.  With local state, I was thinking I could modify the returned data, but not sure what to do when I am using async pipe?

Comment: Yup, Sure you can. I would use `map` or `pluck`. updated answer :)

Comment: I updated my post.  I put your example of using map to get certain properties but getting a syntax error

Comment: Make sure you imported the map operator. `import "rxjs/add/operator/map`

Comment: After I map the data to a new variable `contactCasedata$`, how can I access the variables in my template.  I tried `<p>{{contactCaseData$.officialCaseName}}</p>` but this doesn't work

Comment: In my template, should `<div *ngIf="_caseService.caseData$ | async as caseData">` be changed to `<div *ngIf="contactCaseData$ | async as caseData">`?

Comment: I ended up doing ` this.contactCaseData$ = this._caseService.caseData$.map(data => {
        return {officialCaseName : data.OfficialCaseName}`

Comment: try  `{{(contactCaseData$ | async).officialCaseName}}`. Remember, you have an observable, not an object. `async` takes the observable and return the emitted object for you.

Comment: Great...That worked.  You increased my brain cells.  Thank you so much.

Comment: In my map function, I am filtering on an array, but I sometimes get the error message that filter can't be used on undefined.  I am doing this:     `this.contactCaseData$ = this._caseService.caseData$.map(data => {
        return {officialCaseName : data.OfficialCaseName, content : data.CaseWebsiteContent.filter((i)=> {return i.Route === '/contact'})}
      });`

Comment: its caused by your data.CaseWebsiteContent is null at somepoint. Remember your behavior subject can initailize a value. In the example code i posted, it is just an empty object of `{}`.  See `private caseDataStore = new BehaviorSubject<any>({}); it doesn't have `CaseWebsiteContent` as property
`

Comment: Ok I changed BehaviorSubject to take a strongly typed object and I initialize my CaseWebsiteContent to an empty array, so it doesn't throw an error now, but the nothing is displayed because CaseWebsiteContent is [] instead of being populated with data?

Comment: hmm is your REST call properly returning a response that update the behavior subject? Sounds like the object pass into next is empty.

Comment: I finally got it.  The data was being filled but part of the problem was that the cases didn't match, for example, my service returned OfficialCaseName and in my ts model, I had officialCaseName.

Comment: Oh depends on the back end you use, you can change the serializer. Glad that it's working now, Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a getter in your components

```
//You can use in your .html
//{{caseData}}

get caseData()
{
    return this._caseService.caseData;
}
```

The other idea is subscribe to an Observable of your service.
NOTE: it's better use the HttpClient over the "old" http

Comment: Yeah, I actually just upgraded to Angular 5 yesterday, but haven't completed it.  Can you give me a more verbose example with the getter and subscriptions?  Greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'am a hurry, but using httpClient, you don't need map json. Therefore, with Angular5 you don't need convert to promise just use "do": return this.httpClient.get(url).do(res=> {caseDataStore.next(res);})