# Angular 5 service variable undefined

Tags: angular, service, undefined

Using Angular 5, I have 2 components and a shared service which I want to pass data through, from one component to another.

I subscribe to the variable in my receiving component's oninit and attempt to console.log the result but it is always showing as `undefined`.

The component which makes the initial service function call `_quoteSummaryService.setSelectedPlan()` is called via HTML button click `selectPlan()`, and the object that's passed into is **not** showing as `undefined`.

I can even console.log the object within the service function and it also isn't `undefined`. It's only `undefined` when I call console.log on the receiving components oninit function, after subscribing.

The variable `selectedPlan` is showing as `undefined` when inserted into the receiving components HTML as `{{ selectedPlan? }}`.

**quote-summary.service.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Quote } from '../models/quote-response.model';

@Injectable()
export class QuoteSummaryService {

    constructor(){}

    private _quoteSelectedPlanSource = new Subject<Quote>();
    public quoteSelectedPlan = this._quoteSelectedPlanSource.asObservable();

    setSelectedPlan(selectedPlan:Quote) {
        this._quoteSelectedPlanSource.next(selectedPlan);
    }
}
```

**quote-select-plan.component.ts**: (the component that makes the service call)

```
export class QuoteSelectPlanComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _quoteSummaryService:QuoteSummaryService, private _router: Router) {}

  selectPlan(selectedPlan) {
    this._quoteSummaryService.setSelectedPlan(selectedPlan);
    if (selectedPlan !== undefined) {
      this._router.navigateByUrl('/quote/details/assumptions');
    }
  }
}
```

**quote-summary.component.ts**: (the component that subscribes to the variable but is showing as undefined)

```
export class QuoteSummaryComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _quoteSummaryService:QuoteSummaryService) { }

  public selectedPlan: Quote;

  ngOnInit() {
    this._quoteSummaryService.quoteSelectedPlan.subscribe(plan => { this.selectedPlan = plan });
    console.log(this.selectedPlan) //showing as undefined
  }
}
```

I am a bit stumped now. Here is a list of things I have tried that haven't worked. I feel like I am missing something simple.

- Changing the variable source in the service from type `Subject` to `BehaviorSubject`
- Adding a Getter into the receiving component and trying to access the variable directly from the service.
- Async pipe in the HTML
- Basically everything mentioned in the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48302998/shared-service-variable-is-undefined?rq=1)
- Tried subscribing the the variable in the sending component to see if that would do anything

Comment: Shouldn't the Injectable decorator be like: `@Injectable()` ??

Comment: @AshishRanjan yeah sorry i will update that now

Comment: @AshishRanjan still showing `undefined`

Comment: `console.log(this.selectedPlan)`; under the `subscription`

Comment: RxJS is async so your assigning might occurs after the console.log

Comment: @JEY: He won't be rendering the full component on button click, subsction would already have started before clicking

Comment: If I add a console.log within the actual subscribe method itself, it shows some results, but if i log it outside, it's undefined. my HTML wont render it either  inside {{ }} as it just shows as undefined. Help!

Comment: @blueprintChris: Are you resetting `this.selectedPlan` somewhere else? Your ``HTML` has `{{selectedPlan}}` right?

Comment: I'm not resetting it anywhere else. The only thing that is setting the value is the function call made to the service. I put `selectedPlan.premium` in my HTML but it cannot find property `premium` of `undefined`

Comment: In your html try using like:  `{{selectedPlan?.premium}}` ?

Comment: no prevail im afraid

Comment: @blueprintChris: Please have something like this: `{{selectedPlan | json}}` in your `HTML` and let me know what you see??

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript and with it TypeScript is an async language. When you subscribe to something the current function flow continues, and the subscribed function will only be called once the observable emits. This is -after- the `console.log`.

Change your code to this, and you get what you expect:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this._quoteSummaryService.quoteSelectedPlan.subscribe(plan => { 
    this.selectedPlan = plan;
    console.log(this.selectedPlan);
  });
}
```

You can add additional `console.log` before and after the subscribe, you will see that those are logged before the subscribed function is called.

Even though an `Observable` could be sync, it's always better never to trust on this.

Comment: but how come it won't appear in my HTML and complains its undefined??

Comment: @blueprintChris because it is undefined at the moment the HTML gets rendered for the first time. This happens also before the subscribed function gets called. To prevent any errors with possibly undefined objects, you have to use the safe navigation operator `.?` inside your template.

Comment: @blueprintChris you can see this in action if you also place a `console.log` inside the `ngAfterViewInit` hook. You will see that this is also called before it logs the `this.selectedPlan`. Which means at the time of initial rendering, the `selectedPlan` is still undefined

Comment: @blueprintChris fix what :)? I don't see an error message, or anything. Just a console.log at the wrong place

Comment: It's showing undefined in the HTML. Cannot access the variable in the HTML.

Comment: @blueprintChris but you didn't post your HTML :) that might come in handy

Comment: @blueprintChris you should probably use `BehaviourSubject`. The `.next(selectedPlan)` is called before the `subscribe`. With a `BehaviourSubject` you will get the last emitted value.

Comment: changing `Subject` to `BehaviourSubject` fixed the issue. Feel free to modify your answer to demonstrate this and I will accept.